# PHP/Curl request is not working

Tags: php, curl

phpinfo(); function shows that curl is enabled.
dll statements are also uncommented in the .ini file.
Still  the curl request is not working.

```
<?php
//step1
$cSession = curl_init(); 
//step2
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.google.com");
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
//step3
$result=curl_exec($cSession);
if(curl_errno($cSession)){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($cSession);
}
//step4
curl_close($cSession);
//step5
echo $result;
?>
```

This code shows the error:

Curl error: Failed to connect to 192.168.1.1 port 8080: Timed out

Comment: `192.168.1.1` is normally the IP of your router? Have you got something in your HOSTS file designed to block access to Google

Comment: I've used this code, it's not have any problems. Did you denied google in `hosts` file?

Comment: @VictorGeek Great minds think alike!

Comment: firewall is also turned off

Answer (score 0):

Can you check firewall on that site. I am sure that firewall on that site is blocking traffic to IP address of your server.

Check the DNS resolution as well. Better yet, try to ping 192.168.1.1 from the machine that is not working. Also wget https://192.168.1.1:8080 (from the machine that is not working) will give you detailed error message.

Answer (score -1):

use this code

```
function curl($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();  // Initialising cURL
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // Setting cURL's URL option with the $url variable passed into the function
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // Setting cURL's option to return the webpage data
        $data = curl_exec($ch); // Executing the cURL request and assigning the returned data to the $data variable
        curl_close($ch);    // Closing cURL
        return $data;   // Returning the data from the function
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: You have not added anything here that would make this an answer. Converting it to a function solves nothing